# How do I overlap a dragged item over a dropped item?

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, kendo-grid, kendo-angular-ui

I am trying to copy the data from one kendo grid to another using drag and drop  html5 events[https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp]. When I try to `ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));` , I get the error that data is not the type of `node`. I want that the data to be dropped must overlap over existing data in the drop zone. So how should I achieve the same?

Here's the stackblitz link: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3jkhn?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: take a look to angular material drag and drop component it was added in the version number 7 
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using this one from Angular Material

Hope this help you out a bit.

[Drag and Drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)

Comment: I tried angular material but while dropping an item over existing item, the below item shifts which doesn't allow me to drop over it